# md-button size (angular material)

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm very new to angular-material and I'm using some `md-button` directives. As I'm coming from Bootstrap world, I'm searching for a way to have different sizes for `md-button`s. Something like `btn-xs` and `btn-sm` classes in Bootstrap.

I created a class `md-button-xs` and tried to set size of button using this class with no success. I even tried to resize the button using developer options in Google Chrome but that didn't work too.

How can I have different sizes for `md-button` and other Angular Material components?

Comment: What bothers me most about this whole issue is that there's no concept of a standard 'larger button'. It's easy enough to add your own class, change line-height, flex / width and font-size but isn't material supposed to be about a standardized interface. Small / standard buttons just don't always work well.

Answer (score 16):

We're all (well kind of) new to Angular Material. This serves as my disclaimer to my answer.

I never spent much time with twitter bootstrap, but I can tell you that specifying sizes is probably not as important in the realm of Angular Material.

- Angular Material utilizes [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Specifying specific size is less important in Angular Material, I have found personally. [Demo: Layout > Grid System](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1/#/layout/grid)
- While you can accomplish a lot with grids in ngMaterial (Eg: [grid lists](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1/#/demo/material.components.gridList) and [child alignment](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1/#/layout/alignment)), I recommend seeing if the simple [layout attribute](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1/#/layout/container) works for you "out of the box", to accompany the general usage of Flexbox.

Why not mess around with the buttons in the buttons demo page? Or is there something more specific you are looking to do that you need help with?
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.button

I messed with it a bit for you! Pretty simple stuff once you get going.
http://codepen.io/qvazzler/pen/jPgbQO

```
<md-button flex="15">{{title1}} (Not much)</md-button>
<md-button flex="15" md-no-ink="" class="md-primary">Primary (Not much either)</md-button>
<md-button flex="33" ng-disabled="true" class="md-primary">Disabled (More space for me!)</md-button>
<md-button flex class="md-warn">{{title4}} (I'll have what's left)</md-button>
```

Good luck!

*Post written with reference to [Angular Material version 0.10.1](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1/#/). If you are using a newer version and you can't get familiar results, use the site to change version after browsing to any of my links to figure out what's wrong. And there's always the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).*

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. I had gone throw all of the links you mentioned with no success. My final decision was to not use Angular Material for web apps (for now), maybe I use it for some mobile hybrid apps.

Comment: @Najafsen, what is the success you are looking for? It seems to me that you are still wanting to set specific x and y sizes, which is a perfectly good answer in which Angular Material is not the best way to go. Also, please mark my answer as accepted if you are done on this subject.

Comment: @WilliamS answers should only be accepted if they resolved the concrete problem from the OP's question, not because someone is done on a subject

Comment: @pootzko, so how do I resolve the concrete problem? He has stepped away from the entire "framework".

Comment: I guess you can't solve every problem.. :) read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @pootzko, as a newcomer to StackOverflow, when you have made a dozen of attempts at great answers with 0 rep and without accepted status, it gets frustrating.

Comment: I know, it's just the way it is sometimes.. You're doing great job by helping, keep it up! :) Rep will come eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do your own if you want, for example i did that:

```
    .material-cust-large-button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
.material-cust-medium-button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

And in html:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary material-cust-large-button">text</md-button>
<md-button ui-sref="..." class="md-raised md-primary material-cust-medium-button">text</md-button>
```

And it works as i expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This was kind of tricky for me. The issue was that the min-width is set by Angular Material to 88px. I wanted mine to be VERY small. I was setting width and max-width, but hadn't thought to check min-width. Min-width is set pretty high for a global, common thing like a button... So set the min-width or you'll have problems resizing this if you want it to be small.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your sizes to over-ride the default sizes in the styles.css file with the !important tag they will change. this is the only way that I could set them. I have to clarify that this is for Angular and not AngularJS, however, I would imagine that the main CSS file would have the same benefit in AngularJS

```
    .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  width: 15px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
}

.mat-radio-inner-circle {
  width: 15px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
}
```